# Firebase Messaging Flutter foreground iOS not working

Tags: ios, asp.net, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

It is really weird, in Android it works correctly.
I have a .Net Core Server it sends a msg through firebase using FirebaseAdmin.Messaging
The way to send it is something like this:

```
                // Create a list containing up to 500 registration tokens.               
                var message = new MulticastMessage()
                { 
                    Tokens = registrationTokens,                       
                    Data = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                    {
                        { "class_name", request.ClassName.ToLower() },
                        { "action", request.Action.ToString() },
                        { "id", request.Id },
                        { "type", "update_model" },
                        { "all", all.ToString().ToLower() },
                        { "obj", string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonToSend) ? "" : jsonToSend },
                    },
                };
                await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendMulticastAsync(message);
```

In flutter I receive the msg:

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  generalLog.info('Got a message whilst in the foreground!');
  generalLog.info('Message data: ${message.data}');
});
```

As you can see I send the msg without the param Notification, because I use just to update some process in flutter for instance fetch an object and update the local db in flutter for this reason I don't need to show the notification, in Android it works, but in iOS I never see this enter to the method FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message)...
I realize that if I put the param Notification in C# like this

```
            var message = new MulticastMessage()
            {
                Tokens = registrationTokens,
                Notification = new Notification
                {
                    Body = "background process",
                    Title = "background",
                },
                Data = new Dictionary<string, string> {
                    { "obj", msgToSend},
                    { "type", "chat" }
                },
            };
```

The msg gets in iOS, but I don't want this, because in background I receive a lot of notifications

Comment: Try setting `contentAvailable` or `content-available` to `true` among options when sending with Firebase Messaging.

Comment: @PeterKoltai I already did but the issue reamins, even I download the example in the official repo https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging/example without success, the messages not work without the param notification

Comment: any update on this?